# How to delete completely 2D pointer array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have a 2D pointer matrix in C++ such as,

```
typedef unsigned char  U8;
typedef unsigned int   U32;
int M=10;
int m_L=8;
U8** A = new U8*[M];
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    A[i] = new U8[m_L];
}
```

After setting value in A0, I will write a function which decide delete or not delete M-2 rows in A, depends on the random number is 0 or 1

```
void delete_or_not(U8** A,int M) 
{
  if (rand_num==1){
     for (U32 index = M-2; index < M; ++index){
        delete[] A[index];
     }
  }
}
```

Now, in main function (which contains A memory allocation), I want to free/delete the memory which allocated for A. I can use the code

```
//free A matrix
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    if (i < m_L)
    {
      delete[] A[i];
      A[i] = NULL;
    }
}
delete[] A;
A = NULL;
```

My problem is that, I don't know that A is delete (M-2) rows or not. Hence, above code does clearly delete all memory, if my random number is 0. That means, above code only delete correct memory if M-2 rows is deleted in the `delete_or_not` function. How can delete the A matrix perfectly. Thanks

Finaly, my full code is

```
typedef unsigned char  U8;
typedef unsigned int   U32;
int M=10;
int m_L=8;
U8** A = new U8*[M];
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    A[i] = new U8[m_L];
}
delete_or_not(A,M);
//free A matrix 
//Way 1: will miss M-2 row if delete_or_not function did not delete 2 rows.
// It only correct if rand_num=1
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    if (i < m_L)
    {
      delete[] A[i];
      A[i] = NULL;
    }
}
delete[] A;
A = NULL;

//Way 2- It will correct if the size of A is M by M

for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
      delete[] A[i];
      A[i] = NULL;
}
delete[] A;
A = NULL;
```

Comment: There are more readable names to chose from than `U32`, `U8`, `M`, `m_L` *etc*

Comment: Don't use raw arrays, pointers, `new` or `new[]`, and you won't have to worry about them.

Comment: Also notice that your description and your code is not the same. Your description states: `delete or not delete M-2 rows` but your code actually deletes 2 elements because you have `U32 index = M-2` as initialization of index in the for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set deleted elements to `NULL` and everything will work fine:

```
void delete_or_not(U8** A,int M) 
{
  if (rand_num==1){
     for (U32 index = M-2; index < M; ++index){
        delete[] A[index];
        A[index] = NULL;
     }
  }
}
```

Also, this is not very useful:

```
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
    if (i < m_L)
    {
      delete[] A[i];
      A[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

There's no point advancing `i` from 0 to `M` if you then only "do work" when `i` is smaller then `m_L`.

---

But really, in C++ you should probably use `std::vector<std::vector<U8>>` instead and simply `erase` or `pop_back` to get rid of "rows".

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was wrong explaination. My expected is how can I delete A matrix after call the delete_or_not function. I will update

Comment: @user8430 - did you try my suggested solution?

Answer (score 1):

In `void delete_or_not`you shall set deleted elements to NULL as already proposed by another answer by Amit.

Then Way 2 of your posted code is correct in both cases.

Calling `delete` on a NULL is perfectly legal and doesn't hurt at all.

Way 1 is not working and should be removed.

In summary:

```
void delete_or_not(U8** A,int M) 
{
  if (rand_num==1){
     for (U32 index = M-2; index < M; ++index){
        delete[] A[index];
        A[index] = NULL;    // Add this to your code
     }
  }
} 


// In main somewhere...

// free A
for (U32 i = 0; i < M; ++i)
{
      delete[] A[i];   // Not a problem if the element has already been deleted
                       // because the pointer will be NULL and calling
                       // delete with NULL is OK (and changes nothing)
      A[i] = NULL;
}
delete[] A;
A = NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks. But way 2 will crashed if random_num=1. Thus, 2 rows already deleted in the delete_or_not function. Hence, for =1 to M is not correct

Comment: No, it will not crash if you make the changed proposed by Amit.

Comment: I added it again. Thanks. It worked now. Thanks for your explaination